# Flutter ExpansionPanelList inside a modalBottomSheet doesn't update state

Tags: flutter

I have a Modal Bottom Sheet where I want to put a list of expansions. In order to do so, I made a class to create items for my `ExpansionPanelList`.

```
class FilterItem {
  bool isExpanded;
  final String header;
  final Widget body;
  FilterItem(this.isExpanded, this.header, this.body);
}
```

I simply provide each item with the `isExpanded` boolean to tell whether it's initially expanded or not, the header of the `ExpansionPanel` (works as intended) and the body of the `ExpansionPanel`.

I have a List of items like this:

```
items = <FilterItem>[
    new FilterItem(
        false,
        'Bit Size',
        GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        itemCount: _docs["Bit Size"].length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index) {
            return Text(_docs["Bit Size"].elementAt(index),style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black));
        },
        )
    ),
];
```

I'm testing with one item right now, its body is a `GridView`, I haven't got the chance to test whether it shows correctly because the expanding of the `ExpansionPanel` does not work.

This `List` of items is used with an `ExpansionPanelList` inside the `showModalBottomSheet() method` which I invoke using a button. This is the body of the method:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: (items.length == null) ? 0:items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index) {
        return ExpansionPanelList(
            expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
            setState(() {
                items[index].isExpanded = !items[index].isExpanded;
            });
            },
            children: items.map((FilterItem item) {
            print("b");
            return ExpansionPanel(
                headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                return ListTile(
                    title: new Text(
                        item.header,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                    ));
                },
                isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
                body: item.body,
            );
            }).toList(),
        );
        },
    );
    },
    isScrollControlled: true,
);
```

As you can see, I've set the `isExpanded` property of the `ExpansionPanel` to the value of the item in the list, and in the `ExpansionPanelList` callback, I update it inside a `setState`.

**This is where the problem occurs, the expanding does not work. What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to update state in Bottom Sheet you need to wrap your returned widget by StatefulBuilder like

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context,StateSetter  setStateOfBottomSheet) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
               setStateOfBottomSheet;
                  },
                  child: Text('Hello'))
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    });
```

then you can call this object which i named it in this previous code :setStateOfBottomSheet
when you call it you able to update state of your Bottom sheet